# For taskassigning project，I want the same tasktype tasks can be adjacent as more as possible。

Tags: optaplanner

Below is what I plan, please give me advice:

(1) In the Task class, add a `CustomShadowVariable`:

```
 @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = 
       NumOfAdjacentUpdatingVariableListener.class,
       sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = 
             "previousTaskOrEmployee") })
  private Integer numOfAdjacent;
```

(2) In the class  `NumOfAdjacentUpdatingVariableListener`:

```
@Override
public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<TaskAssigningSolution> 
       scoreDirector, Task task) {
    //update number of adjacent tasks : numOfAdjacent
}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<TaskAssigningSolution> 
       scoreDirector, Task task) {
    //update number of adjacent tasks : numOfAdjacent
}
```

(3) In the constraints，add a constraint to reward the `numOfAdjacent`.

[image: Task Assignment Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without a custom shadow variable. Simply add a new constraint that penalizes every pair of adjacent tasks if they have different types. This constraint will push OptaPlanner to reorder tasks and minimize the number of adjacent tasks with different types.

The constraint could look like this:

```java
private Constraint adjacentTaskDifferentTypes(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
            .join(Task.class, equal(Task::getNextTask, Function.identity()))
            .filter((t1, t2) -> !t1.getTaskType().equals(t2.getTaskType()))
            .penalize("Adjacent task have different types",
                    // constraint weight
                    BendableScore.ofSoft(HARD_LEVELS, SOFT_LEVELS, 0, 3));
}
```

This constraint works on the TaskAssignment example in https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner. Try implementing a similar constraint using your project's domain model.

Then tweak the resulting solution by changing the constraint's priority. You can adjust the priority by changing the constraint weight:

1. Change the match weight (`3` in the code snippet above) to change the constraint priority relative to other constraints affecting the same score level.
2. Change the constraint's score level (`0` in the code snippet above) to give the constraint higher priority than all constraints on lower score levels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But would your method better than adding a custom shadow variable, because I want the adjacent tasks sublist could be as long as possible, as you can see in the picture, not just two  adjacent tasks.

Comment: Yes, my proposal is able to produce results similar to the picture linked in the question. As I said, some additional constraint weight tweaking might be necessary. For example, if task type homogeneity is a top priority, you might want to add a new soft score level for it.

Comment: The proposed constraint rewards OptaPlanner for eliminating adjacent tasks with different types. In other words it leads to maximizing chains of tasks of the same type. Try it out, you'll understand. You should also write a test for the constraint. See https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsTesting. That will give you confidence that the constraint has the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks again. My task type is for produce continuous, that is the same type product can be produced successively, so there is no any priority in type. I will try the 2 methods, and see the results. Thanks a lot.